# Clustering Latitude Longitude data in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, cluster-analysis, latitude-longitude

I have a database with Latitude and Longitude values. What I want to do is to cluster these data in order to get less results every time that I search the database. Any ideas how to implement this?

This is a similar question:
[Clustering Lat/Longs in a Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330056/clustering-lat-longs-in-a-database?rq=1)

Comment: Are you saying you want to limit the result set to a radius of a provided lat/long or something?

Comment: @Ray Yes, given the values I want to group them in 3 clusters. For example if we have 100 points and 30 of them are different but close to a specific place, and the same with the other 30 and 40 values. We want 3 clusters which contain: Cluster1(30 values), Cluster2(30 values) Cluster3(40 values) OR Better would be if I could send a center point and take as a result 30 values that are very close to this point

Comment: Is the longitude and latitude in 2 columns? So basically, you want to be able to specify a point and return the 30 closest records (or 40 depending on your request)?

Comment: @Ray I stored them in two columns separately and in one column as a spatial point in order to do some testing. I want to try giving a specific point in one case and not in the other case so leave the procedure to recognize that this 30 points are very close so put them in one group.

Comment: @Ray So two cases: One case: Given the specific points group data based on that points. Second case: Group the data in clusters and choose randomly initial points

Comment: Consider loading your data into a tool better suited for clustering than MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

It's not too crazy to find the closest records to a given longitude/latitude.  Assuming you've a table `location` with columns `longitude` and `latitude` you could do the following (substitute out the  and  with the values from your point.

```
   SELECT id, latitude, longitude,  
               ROUND(6353 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((<point_latitude> - 
                      abs(latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS( <point_latitude>  * pi()/180 ) 
                      * COS( abs(latitude) *  pi()/180) 
                      * POWER(SIN(( <point_longitude> - longitude) 
                      *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) )), 2) AS distance
     FROM location
     ORDER BY distance ASC 
     LIMIT 30;
```

You could do similar with spatial functions.

Comment: Ok I understand but what in case of not giving a specific point? I found that kmeans can do this but I don't know how to implement.

Comment: @GeorgeMelidis Not sure how you'd implement kmeans clustering, but check out this http://jonisalonen.com/2012/k-means-clustering-in-mysql/  It looks like a stored proc is needed

Comment: Thanks Ray I have seen this article. It's the only one I found :-). I'm going to try it and if I have good results in my data I post!