# How to set a Google Maps Marker Icon based on current map filters and a combination of HashMap strings the marker has

Tags: java, icons, hashmap, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

It would be very helpful if anyone has any suggestions on the most efficient approach for implementing code to set a map marker icon based on:

- Filters defined by the user dictating what markers to display( `boolean` )
- Keys contained in a `HashMap<String, Integer>` associated with the marker - in `class CrimePoint`

**Filters Options defined by the user:**

```
    boolean displayAntiSocialBehaviourMarkers;
    boolean displayBurglaryMarkers;
    boolean displayCriminalDamageArsonMarkers;
    boolean displayDrugsMarkers;
    boolean displayOtherTheftMarkers;
    boolean displayPubDisorderWeaponsMarkers;
    boolean displayRobberyMarkers;
    boolean displayShopliftingMarkers;
    boolean displayVehicleCrimeMarkers;
    boolean displayViolentCrimeMarkers;
    boolean displayOtherCrimeMarkers;
```

Each Marker is created with a `CrimePoint` which is a class containing all the information necessary to plot a marker

**Crime Point Class Variables:**

```
private final Double latitude;
private final Double longitude;
private final String title;

//SNIPPET
//The HashMap storing the categories associated with this CrimePoint.
//Category name is the key and the number of crimes in that category is the Value
//
private Map<String, Integer> crimeCategories;

//An integer to hold the references to the icon image to use
//Example: R.drawable.image002;
private int iconResource;
```

**Marker Icons:**

There are **12** different Marker Icons available for the map. One for each filter Option [given above] and a special case marker (Multiple Crimes) where: 
 - The `CrimePoint` has more than one Crime Category (`crimeCategories.size() > 1` ) **AND** 
 
 - More than One Crime category contained in the `CrimePoint` is set to visible using the filter Options

The Marker will only be drawn if there is a (or multiple) crimeCategory that is being shown.

Any help or suggestions would be great as I've spent ages tackling with the logic I need for this and haven't come up with much.

Note: Each time the filter options are changed by the user this function will need to be invoked to change icons on the map and hide/show markers.

Comment: We are talking about the native API rather than javascript?

Comment: Yes within Eclipse on a `GoogleMap` object. Not javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should consider changing your representation.  Begin with an enumeration of the crime types:

```
enum CrimeType { AntiSocialBehaviour, ..., Count }
```

Now your flags can be created as an enum set:

```
EnumSet<CrimeType> showMarkers = new EnumSet<CrimeType>();
```

This works like a regular Java `Set` but is more efficient.  Use them within markers rather than a hash if the power of the hash is not needed.

For turning markers on and off, note [the visibility attribute in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker).  When a filter flag is changed, traverse the list of markers setting visibility appropriately. Then invalidate the map fragment or view. The drawing time will dominate the visibility setting time, so this is as efficient as it needs to be.

I am inferring that you have many markers from the question about efficiency.  If you have so many markers that the map becomes confused by overlaps, then you must implement a merge algorithm to represent multipler markers with one.  I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748150/deconflicting-markers-in-map-overlays) earlier on this subject and received no response.  My solution explained there works quite well, though not as quickly as I'd like (2-3 seconds with about 15,000 markers on a Nexus tablet).

For non-standard marker appearance, study [the documentation here under "Change the Default Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker).

It's pretty clear.  If you have specific questions and show code, we can help with details.

Comment: Hi, I had considered using enums for the Crime types as the Strings will always be the same. However I am not very familiar with using enums and the list of Crime Points & thier associate categories are formulated from running through an Array of JSONObjects creating or updating a new Crime point. I had discounted enums as I would need to give a value to the category that would likely change when running through the JSON.

With regard to to the visibility I know there is a setting you can pass to the marker; currently it is just the logic behind this. I am considering an extra field

Comment: ... (on or off) which will have to be configured at the same time the icon is chosen. <br>
The number of `CrimePoint`s can range from `0` to around `4000` but my code currently groups some of these as they can happen in the same location. However you are correct, my map looks cluttered and has too much "data" for the user to interpret. I was meaning to implement a merger such as "MarkerClusterer" so I will definitely read this post :).

Comment: It's probably worth the time to learn about enums. They're flexible. Each enum value is essentially an instance of an implicit parent class, which can define data instance values and member functions.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html.

Comment: Funnily enough I was reading that earlier. Have just implemented an enum like below which should make it easier once its been implemented through out: <br>

`public enum CrimeCategory {
    ASBO ("Anti Social Behaviour"),
    ....
     private  String category;
 CrimeCategory (String category) {
  this.category = category;
 }
`