# Merge MapView child views when they overlap

Tags: android, android-mapview, overlap, pins

I use MapView and need to display complex pins on it. I add pin on map using addView() with MapView.LayoutParams with MODE_MAP. So, views on map moving with map.

I add about 20 pins and when I reduce map zoom, pins overlap each other.

How can I merge overlapping pins in one pin?

UPD 1:

For each pin I know rect which it place on MapView. There is fast algorithm to find rects overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

You can test reactangle overlaping with:

```
Rect rect1, rect2;
if(rect1.intersect(rect2)
  //do something
```

On this message is a nice algothim to merge pins when they overlap: [Merging Pins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989524/android-mapview-merging-overlapping-markers-into-a-new-marker)

good luck.

Comment: Merging Pins algoritm not applicable for my case, I can not override draw method i.e. I not use overlay for adding items to map. rect1.intersect(rect2) - I know this method, but I need test 20 or more (up to 200) rects overlaping and I need fast algoritm for it.